# Java lambda expressions - explicit target type

Tags: java, lambda, syntax

Consider functional interfaces `A` and `B extends A`. Is it possible to create an instance implementing not only `A` but also `B` with a lambda expression when only `A` is required?

Example:

```
interface A {
    void foo();
}

interface B extends A {}

void bar(A arg) {
    System.out.println(arg instanceof B);
}

/* somewhere in a block */
    bar( () -> {} ); // Prints "false"
```

How could I call `bar(A)` so that it prints `true`?

I would find this useful in event listeners, where subinterfaces could specify additional data about the listener, e.g. if a `Listener` also implements `ConcurrentListener`, it is invoked concurrently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply do a cast to tell the compiler the type you want:

```
A a = (B)() -> someAction();
System.out.println(a instanceof B); // true
```

> I would find this useful in event listeners, where subinterfaces could specify additional data about the listener, e.g. if a Listener also implements ConcurrentListener, it is invoked concurrently.

That sounds like bad design (though I can't explain why...). Maybe you could have a `isConcurrent` method in the interface that implementers need to implement?

Comment: Nice! For those like me who were wondering how a lambda can be automagically cast to an interface [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28509596/314291).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As for your workaround using new methods, that is exactly what I would have done if I wasn't trying to make listeners `@FunctionalInterface`s.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly cast lambda expression to B:

```
bar((B)() -> {});
```

or assign lambda expression to a variable:

```
B lambda = () -> {};
bar(lambda);
```